# convert date/time from local server time to time zone?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting the time and date as a time stamp into my table in a query, and this is showing as the local server time. My local server is in america.

I am trying to convert the local time to time zone specific - Europe/London.

i am preferably wanting to insert the timezone specific time upon it being inserted into the table, however i have been having a lot of problems with this and everything i do doesn't work.

so now im simply trying to convert the time from local to time zone specific when i echo it out. and this gives this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/content/31/9118831/html/ptbadmin/stats.php on line 79
```

can someone please show me where im gonig wrong. 
my table looks like this:

```
    session_id | user_ip | session_start|
    1            1.1.1.1   2013-04-08 00:15:24
    2            1.1.1.1   2013-04-08 00:15:24
```

here is my code:

```
     $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NULL);";
                    mysql_query($sql, $connection);

   <?
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_sessions");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo"<div class=\"session_id\">{$row['session_id']}</div>";

       echo"<div class=\"user_ip\">{$row['user_ip']}</div>";

           $dt_obj = new DateTime($row2['session_start']." UTC");
      $dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
      echo"<div class=\"session_start\">$formatted_date_long=date_format($dt_obj, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')</div>"; 


     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` on top of your php script? ie `<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); //rest of your code ?>` You can also set timezone in mysql using `SET time_zone = timezone;`
 For details on list of supported timezones visit  http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php and for mysql visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html
Tweaking your code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()); // Your required format
$sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_sessions (session_id, user_ip, session_start, session_end) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', $timestamp, NULL);";
mysql_query($sql, $connection);  
?>

<?php
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_sessions");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo"<div class=\"session_id\">{$row['session_id']}</div>";
      echo"<div class=\"user_ip\">{$row['user_ip']}</div>";
      echo"<div class=\"session_start\">{$row['session_start']}</div>"; 
     }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use like this... Change:

> date_format($dt_obj, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')

To:

> $dt_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');